# Creating a new content type with the same name as an existing content type

Tags: drupal-7

I have a problem with creating a new content type in Drupal 7.

I have an existing content type, say 'cats'.

I renamed 'cats' to 'cats_old' (both the human readable name and the machine name) and am trying to create a new, different content type with the name 'cats', but Drupal just updates 'cats_old' and doesn't let me create a new content type called 'cats'.

Is there a know issue/fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your scenario it happened with me as well. I found out that 'cats' content type is not showing in content type list or add content page but there is an entry for 'cats' content type in 'node_type' table. I don't understand what the exact issue is but there is a [Node Convert](http://drupal.org/project/node_convert) module which may help you in converting the node from current content type to another type and transferring content type fields as well.